# Create react app build failed in Gitlab CI runner / Google cloud

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, gitlab-ci, create-react-app

I have a create react app with docker which is running fine on my local machine. If I run Gitlab CI runner locally, the command  `npm build` succeed. But if I do the same command in remote server ( Gitlab CI / Google Cloud) , it always fails with the following message :

```
./src/assets/img/logo_blue.png  
Error: Cannot find module './validate'
```

The problem seems not to be related to related to this issue : [Why is Create React App build failing in Gitlab CI Runner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57231068/why-is-create-react-app-build-failing-in-gitlab-ci-runner). From the error message, I can guess a path problem. For some reasons, inside Gitlab CI runner the path: src is pointing to not my react app src folder.

Should I set the root path somewhere? The configuration is as follows:

Docker

```
FROM node:10.16-alpine as build-deps
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

#ngnix server
# artifact is recheable on port 80
FROM nginx:1.13.12-alpine
# expose port 
EXPOSE 80
# perms to write 
RUN set -x ; \
    addgroup -g 82 -S www-data ; \
    adduser -u 82 -D -S -G www-data www-data && exit 0 ; exit 1

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /usr/share/nginx/html/*
RUN chmod -R 0755 /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# use conf.d to handle redirect aka reload point to root index.html
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf 

#copy assets
COPY --from=build-deps /app/build  /usr/share/nginx/html
# command
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

my gitlab ci is

```
image: node:10
cache:
  key: build-cache
  paths:
    - node_modules/
    - /root/.npm/_logs
stages:
  - build

## build

build:master:
  image: docker:19.03.1
  #image: tmaier/docker-compose:latest
  stage: build
  only:
    - dev
    - master
  allow_failure: false
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  services:
    - docker:19.03.1-dind
  before_script:
    # docker login -u $DOCKER_KEY -p $DOCKER_ACCESS
  script:
    - docker build  -f ./client/Dockerfile ./client
    # - docker-compose up --build --no-start
    #- docker build -t $DOCKER_CLIENT_TAG -f ./client/Dockerfile ./client
    #- docker build -t $DOCKER_PROXY_TAG -f ./proxy/Dockerfile ./proxy
    #- docker push $DOCKER_CLIENT_TAG
    #- docker push $DOCKER_PROXY_TAG
```

and the jsx file looks like this

```
import BlueLogo from "./../../../assets/img/logo_blue.png";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the tsconfig.json, just add "baseUrl": "./".
 For some reason, on my local machine, typescript could resolve the path without  explicit configuration but failed on remote